# Destroying and Recreating a TK Window in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, window, tk-toolkit

I create a root window in thread using python. Then next is I need to destroy it and create a new window but an error was out saying that threads can only be started once. How can I start a new window form?

```
class SignUp(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.mw=Tkinter.Tk()
        self.mw.geometry("800x600""+290+50")
        self.mw.title("Registration Form")
        self.mw.resizable(width=False,height=False)
    self.regs=Tkinter.Button(self.canvas, text= "Log-in",font="{Arial} 12 {bold}",bg='black',fg='white',command=self.login)
    self.regs.place(rely=0.82,relx=0.1,relwidth=0.30)
        self.start()

    def login(self):
        self.mw.destroy()
        self.mw.geometry("650x700""+350+20")
        self.mw.title("Py cos")
        self.mw.resizable(width=False,height=False)
        self.canvas= Tkinter.Canvas(self.mw)
        self.canvas.pack(expand='yes',fil='both')
        self.photo= Tkinter.PhotoImage(file='Image/vote.gif')
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0,image=self.photo,anchor='nw')

def run(self):
    self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.client.connect(('localhost',500))
    #self.client.connect(('169.254.57.141',500))
    self.rec=self.client.recv(1024)
    self.canvas.create_text(105,595,text=self.rec, font="{Arial} 8 {bold}", fill = 'yellow')


if __name__=="__main__":
    SignUp().mw.mainloop()
```

This code gives me

```
RuntimeError: threads can only be started once
```

how can I create a window, destroy it, and create it again while avoiding this error?

Comment: Sorry, you have provided *very few details* about your problem, so it is virtually impossible for anyone to help you.  For a start, which windowing framework are you using?  PyGTK? PyQt? wxPython?  Tkinter?  Something else?  Most importantly, please **show us the code you're running**.  It's so much harder to help you without seeing your code.

Comment: Im using Tkinter Im sorry, what I mean is I need to create a new window without making another thread

Answer (score 0):

If you use threading you can do something like this:-

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread
class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.g=Tk()
        self.th=Thread(target=self.g.mainloop)
        self.th.start()
    def destroy(self):
        self.g.destroy()
```

If you don't use threading you can put an abort button in your app like this:-

```
class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.g=Tk()
        self.bu=Button(self.g,text='Abort',command=self.Abort)
        self.bu.pack()
        self.g.mainloop()
    def Abort(self):
        self.g.destroy()
```

I think your code should be this:-

```
class SignUp(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.mw=Tkinter.Tk()
        self.mw.geometry("800x600""+290+50")
        self.mw.title("Registration Form")
        self.mw.resizable(width=False,height=False)
        self.regs=Tkinter.Button(self.mw, text= "Log-in",font="{Arial} 12 {bold}",bg='black',fg='white',command=self.login)
        self.regs.place(rely=0.82,relx=0.1,relwidth=0.30)
        self.start()

    def login(self):
        self.mw.destroy()
        self.mw=Tkinter.Tk()
        self.mw.geometry("650x700""+350+20")
        self.mw.title("Py cos")
        self.mw.resizable(width=False,height=False)
        self.canvas= Tkinter.Canvas(self.mw)
        self.canvas.pack(expand='yes',fill='both')
        self.photo= Tkinter.PhotoImage(file='Image/vote.gif')
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0,image=self.photo,anchor='nw')
        self.mw.mainloop()


    if __name__=="__main__":
        SignUp().mw.mainloop()
```

And it doesn't show any error.

Comment: I add the def run(self): in the code as I forgot to put it, it shows error